# Can I use Tox to test two packages that are developed side-by-side?

Tags: python, testing, pytest, tox

I have two Python packages in the same repo - one is an autogenerated low-level REST client (from openapi-generator), and the other is a wrapper that uses those low-level methods to accomplish higher-level goals.

When there are changes in the API definition I'm generating from, I often have to make corresponding changes to the wrapper.  So when I run my tests, it needs to take the version from my working directory for BOTH packages.  For example, I could accomplish it by doing this:

```
virtualenv env
source env/bin/activate
pip install -e autogen_client
pip install -e wrapper
py.test wrapper/tests/
```

Is there a way to have `tox` do this mucking around with `virtualenv` and `pip`?  Like can you give relative paths in the `deps` field?  Or is my use case weird enough that I just have to do it myself?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that yes, you can make tox act like this.

```
[tox]
envlist = py35,py36
skipsdist = True  # since there's no top-level package

[testenv]
deps =
    -eautogen_client
    -ewrapper
    pytest

commands =
    py.test wrapper/tests/
```

Nice!